# how to detect if openGL/card supports non power of 2?

Tags: c, opengl, textures

What is the best way to detect if a graphics card and compiled openGL binary supports textures which are not a power of 2 at run time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check with `glGet` for [ARB_texture_non_power_of_two](http://www.nvidia.com/dev_content/nvopenglspecs/GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two.txt) or use GLEW.

**Edit to reflect the comments:** As of OpenGL 2.0 this feature is required and ARB_texture_non_power_of_two need not be defined. How to find the current version is described [here](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_tell_what_version_of_OpenGL_I.27m_using.3F). As Jerry points out: Depending on the GPU the feature might be implemented in software and the performance wont be great if you use textures with a non-power-of-two size.

Comment: You also need to check for OpenGL 2.0+, as it has <code>ARB_texture_non_power_of_two</code> implicitly (I *think* GLEW does this automatically)

Comment: @wump Do you have any documentation on this? My google-fu seems useless here and there is no such mentioning anywhere in the documentation. `glewinfo` listed it fine.

Comment: GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two is core in OpenGL 2.0 and beyond.

Notice that some old cards expose this extension, but have some limitations for NPOT textures, such as limited wrap modes.

Comment: So an OpenGL 1.x implementation would never support non Po2 textures?

Comment: @Nick: an OpenGL 1.x implementation can support it via ARB_texture_non_power_of_two. From OpenGL 2.0 onwards, it's required rather than an extension -- but also be aware that in some cases, it's supported, but in software so performance is really poor.

Comment: Sadly, most modern ATI boards do not support hardware NPOT2, so I'd definitely continue treating the flag as conditional, rather than assuming it and eating the performance hit.

Comment: pmr: When a OpenGL implementation advertises a certain version of the API, it is not required to list the extensions that are a requirement for that version anymore. This means that OGL 2.0 implementations can either list or not list ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, but in both cases it will be present.
AFAIK there is no way to check whether it is supported in HW or emulated. That's the way OGL works.