# Problem texture mapping a quad in OpenGL with Ortho2D

Tags: java, opengl, texture-mapping, lwjgl

The following code produces the image that follows. The image I am using for the background is 640 x 480, as is the displayMode. The texture *background* is a .bmp and is loaded with the Slick texture loader. I am confuse to why it is not filling the Quad and why it is reflected.
EDIT: The background of my OpenGL scene is pink, the black you see is from the Quad created. The background image is the green block with a 2px light blue border with "test" plastered on it.

```
private void renderBackground(){
    float w = displayMode.getHeight()/2;
    float h = displayMode.getWidth()/2;

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    GL11.glLoadIdentity();
    GLU.gluOrtho2D(-w, w, -h, h);

    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPushMatrix();

    GL11.glLoadIdentity();      
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    if(useTextures)background.bind();
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(-w,-h);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(w,-h);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(w, h);

    GL11.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    GL11.glVertex2f(-w, h);

    GL11.glEnd();

    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
    GL11.glPopMatrix();
}
```

[image: OpenGL Texture mismapping]

Now when I add `GL11.glTranslatef(20.0f, 20.0f, 0.0f);` you will notice that the pink appears, which is the colour created int my "initGL" method:
        `GL11.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.75f, 0.796f, 0.0f);`[image]

My GL_PROJECTION contains the following before pushing it, my GL_MODELVIEW is unmodified when renderBackground() is called.

```
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION); // Select The Projection Matrix
    GL11.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Projection Matrix

    // Calculate The Aspect Ratio Of The Window
    GLU.gluPerspective(45.0f, (float) displayMode.getWidth() / (float) displayMode.getHeight(), 0.1f, 25.0f);
    //position camera
    GLU.gluLookAt(5.0f, 3.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select The Modelview Matrix
```

Comment: "it is displaying so incorrectly": And the correct display would be...what?

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I was expecting the entire polygon to be filled with my texture.

Comment: It looks like it is filled.  Do you want the polygon to fill the entire viewport?  If so, what are the contents of your `GL_PROJECTION` and `GL_MODELVIEW` matrices before you push them?

Comment: I thank you for trying to assist me, I edited my question to show my reasoning that the black is part of the polygon.

Comment: gluLookAt belongs in the modelview matrix, not the projection matrix. The projection matrix is kind of the "lens" of the OpenGL camera, but only the lens. The viewpoint is set, by opposite movement of the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need more information to determine the problem, but here is a list with some possibilities.

1) You are using an older video card, which does not support texture non-power of 2, since you are using a library to load the texture, maybe it is detecting it, creating a power of two image, and filling it with black.

2) You (or some library you are using) changed the matrix of the texture matrix stack, and it is changing the texture coordinates.

3) You are doing something wrong when you load the texture (or call the library to do so).

The first thing I would check is if your video card supports texture non-power of 2 extension. You can check it at runtime, see [how to detect if openGL/card supports non power of 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046597/how-to-detect-if-opengl-card-supports-non-power-of-2)

Comment: Thanks, as it turns out, textures that are not powers of 2 are not supported.

Answer (score 0):

What I see first, is that you compute

```
float w = displayMode.getHeight()/2;
float h = displayMode.getWidth()/2;
```

switched?

Second, the texture could be flipped because the loader flipped it (when I remember right this happened to me, too especially with BMPs).